# Using cx_oracle to connect to DB but getting a TNS error

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Hello I am trying to connect to my db using cx_oracle. The issue that I am having is that I get TNS error that says the host is unreachable. See below for the line of code that I am currently running.

```
cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@TNSNAME")
```

Comment: What is the exact error?  Do you have a tnsnames.ora file?  Is `tnsname` in it?  What is the definition?  Can you `tnsping` the TNS alias?

Comment: A ORA-12543 error code shows up when I run the code

Comment: _"A ORA-12543 error code shows up when I run the code"_   And what of the other questions that Justin asked?  What did you discover _when you googled ora-12543_?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot check your network, TNS entry, hostname, user or anything. Please, provide more details

Comment: And I cannot find this type of connection parameters in [the documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html)

Comment: @astentx that connect string format is mentioned in the API doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you wanted to ask what could be the causes for this error.

ORA-12543 means that your alias was found in the tnsnames.ora and that the entry is syntactically correct. Next phase in the connection is to resolve the hostname[s] in the address list of your tns entry.

This is where the possible causes of ORA-12543 start.

1. hostname does not resolve to an ip address
2. the ip address is not reachable on the port of the address that is tried
3. the database server is down
4. a firewall is blocking your access to the mentioned host
5. your driver is not functional

Depending on what your research brings as the root cause, there will be a best fitting option to solve that but my magic bowl is a bit vague at this moment.